# onPressed of an Image I want to place that image in other page's container in flutter, How can I achieve this?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-layoutbuilder

I have a Home page for an ecommerce website and I am showing every product in image format on click of every product(image) I want that image to be filled up in next screen which is of info screen of product that also contains the product (image) and some other related stuff. I want to build info page only a single time and just change the product image and other stuff accordingly as per the image (product) being clicked. How can I achieve this I am new to flutter and dont know this logic i came across valuelistenablebuilder but not getting how can i achieve this, Please Help.
Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Flutter is providing this support by using the `Hero` widget. Find the code snippets below.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(HeroApp());

class HeroApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Transition Demo',
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main Screen'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'imageHero',
          child: Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            return DetailScreen();
          }));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'imageHero',
            child: Image.network(
              'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Make sure the `Hero.tag` property should be maintained as same for both pages.

[Refer the link for more details](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-hero-widgets-in-flutter-d34f441eb026)