# How to access variable from different class ? Flutter (I want to change background image onpress)

Tags: flutter, class, dart, variables, state

I'm struggling to find way to access variable from different class. I want to change background image of decorationImage on button click. But because I do not want to rebuild entire state/page just the background I put the code to different class, but I'm not sure how to access _imagepath1 or _imagepath2 from other class.

```
class CustomMainPageState extends State<SecondRoute> {
  Color myColor = Color(0xff5D6592);

 
  String _imagepath1 = "images/image3.jpg";

  String _imagepath2 = "images/image4.jpg";
  

  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Container(
        //color: Colors.transparent,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
            image: DecorationImage(
                image: AssetImage(_imagepath1), fit: BoxFit.cover)),
        child: Scaffold(
```

```
    class background extends StatefulWidget {
      backgroundG createState() => backgroundG();
    }
    
    class backgroundG extends State<background> {
      @override
      Widget buildbottom() {
        return Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 25,
                backgroundColor: Colors.white,
                child: IconButton(
                  icon: Image.asset('images/icon2.png'),
                  onPressed: () => setState(() {
                    //_imagefile1 = _imagefile2;
                  }),
                ),
              ),
            ]);
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Container(
          child: Row(
            children: [
              SizedBox(height: 100),
              buildbottom(),
              //SizedBox(height: 10),
              //SizedBox(height: 10),//puts empty box to space things out
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Thank you for helping!

Comment: this is duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/66831198/13984728

Comment: I think using a state management solution will help, for example, have the bgPath in a provider so you can change it independent of the current state.

Answer (score 1):

For passing one image to different class you can use flutter `hero` widget,

below is sample code of working with [Hero](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/animations/hero-animations) widget check [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Hero-class.html) also for more info about hero widget

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(HeroApp());

class HeroApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Transition Demo',
      home: MainScreen(),
    );
  }
}

class MainScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Main Screen'),
      ),
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Hero(
          tag: 'imageHero',
          child: Image.network(
            'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) {
            return DetailScreen();
          }));
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

class DetailScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        child: Center(
          child: Hero(
            tag: 'imageHero',
            child: Image.network(
              'https://picsum.photos/250?image=9',
            ),
          ),
        ),
        onTap: () {
          Navigator.pop(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

for passing data between widgets or class I would suggest you to use [InheritedWidget class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/InheritedWidget-class.html) or any state management like `provider`, `bloc`, `getx`  to know more about this check this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d_m5csmrf7I) and [documentation](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/data-and-backend/state-mgmt/options) and if you just want to pass single image then refer this [blog](https://medium.com/flutter-community/simple-ways-to-pass-to-and-share-data-with-widgets-pages-f8988534bd5b)

Comment: Hello, thank you for replying. Im struggling to apply this code to my one, where do i put the `CustomMainPageState instance = new CustomMainPageState();` Would that be in the my backgroundg class?

Comment: I have added some reference to last of my answer check them out and  If my answer was useful, click the upvote button (▲) to the left of it. If it answered your question, click the checkmark (✓) to accept it. That way others know that you've been (sufficiently) helped. Also see https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers